# How do C++ type traits intersect with C-style allocation, deallocation, and data copies

Tags: c++, types, type-traits

The object-oriented semantics of C++ allow us to enforce all kinds of invariants about the data we compute with. This, in turn, gives us all kinds of guarantees about - among other things - memory safety: if I construct an object, I am (hopefully) guaranteed that it will be in a valid, usable state. Likewise, if I destruct it, RAII semantics will ensure that the necessary memory is freed and that everything is cleaned up as necessary.

But C++ does not exist in a world that always abides by these semantics. Most notably, it exists in a world where `malloc`, `free`, and `memcpy` exist. Of course, we usually avoid these functions in "modern" C++, but there are cases where we really cannot avoid them. As a motivating example, consider the case where we write code for NVIDIA GPUs with CUDA; there, we can't neatly construct objects in memory, because the host cannot (in general) write to that memory. Thus, we need to rely on functions like `cudaMemcpy` to move data to the GPU.

My question is: how do allocation, deallocation, and copy functions like the ones we see in CUDA relate to C++ semantics, and how can we - via type traits - ensure that any memory operations we perform conform with the rules of C++? More concretely, what type trait, or which type traits, are sufficient to *guarantee* that certain operations on a type can be performed without violating C++ semantics? Also, I'm looking for the *minimally restrictive* type traits to make these guarantees, such that the largest possible set of types can be supported. In practice, this boils down into (I believe) three smaller questions:

1. Which minimal (set of) type trait(s) *guarantees* that allocating (but **not** constructing) memory leaves it in a valid state that is ready for use? The obvious candidate for this would be `std::is_trivially_default_constructible`. Is this type trait strong enough to enforce the requirement? And is there no less restrictive type trait that provides the same guarantee?
2. Which minimal (set of) type trait(s) *guarantees* that deallocating (but **not** destructing) memory does not violate the object's destructor semantics? Here, the obvious candidate would be `std::is_trivially_destructible`, but the same question arises: is this sufficient, or am I missing some edge cases?
3. Which minimal (set of) type trait(s) *guarantees* that copying (but, again, **not** constructing or assigning) memory from one location to another, leaves the destination in a valid, properly constructed state (assuming the source memory is, itself, properly constructed)? In this particular case, I am more confident that `std::is_trivially_copyable` satisfies the requirement, because the documentation (on *cppreference*) reads that types satisfying these traits are the only ones which can be safely copied using `std::memcpy`, and I would assume the same would apply to - for example - `cudaMemcpy`.

Comment: Those traits look right.

Comment: I use this static check on my own `memset` destination type: `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*dst)>>::value, "not trivially copyable");`

Comment: Note that `malloc` won't satisfy your needs, even for a trivially-constructible object. You would (at the very least) need `calloc`, or `malloc` followed by `memset` to set all locations to zero. That *may* be sufficient, unless you have a platform where zero numbers aren't represented by all-zero bits.